# Submitting a pipeline to microk8s.kubeflow, using kfp.Client python api

Tags: microk8s, kfp

I installed microk8s and is working. I can upload and run a pipeline using the UI. Now I installed kfp python api (issues exist with the cli too) and I'm trying to submit a pipeline using the cli. Here is the api for the client function:

```
def __init__(self, host=None, client_id=None, namespace='kubeflow', other_client_id=None, other_client_secret=None, existing_token=None, cookies=None):
```

I'm only passing the host 10.64.140.43.xip.io, but it fails with

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Which suggests that the host and/or other default parameters are wrong. Unfortunately there is no doc whatsoever anywhere. My guess is I should somehow provide a user pass too. Can someone provide some concrete steps to filling the parameters so thet I can submit a pipeline programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out ?